# jquery: name timeout of anchor dynamic using its id

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, timeout, settimeout

Hej!

I might be a blockhead here, but I can't figure this out;

I'm building a horizontal menu with the basic hover() function in javascript. When you leave an anchor, there's a short timout before the hover effect disappears.

So what I want to do: Name the Timeout after the ID of the anchor, where the mouseleave is triggered in order to stop the right Timeout again on mouseenter.

On Mouseenter i check which anchor is hovered by getting the id, i cancel the timeout for this id and i add the hvr-Class to the hovered anchor:

```
var t = $(this).attr('id');
clearTimeout(t);
$(this).addClass('hvr');
```

and on Mouseleave I want to do basically this:

```
$(this).attr('id') = setTimeout('doSoemthing()',66);
```

But that causes an error, because the expression isn't allowed on the left side of the =. I thought about something like this:

```
var ts = $(this).attr('id');
ts = setTimeout('doSoemthing()',66);
```

but that doesn't work either, because it just overwrites the variable t. Instead I want to kind of 'print' the value of the variable for the Timeout-Name. If i used fixed Timeout-Names, everything works like a charm, but than there's only one (the same) timeout for every link, which doesn't do it.

Is there a way to do this? Or am I off the track?

That's the complete function:

```
$("nav a").hover(

  function(){

  // On MouseEnter
    var t = $(this).attr('id');
    clearTimeout(t);
    $(this).addClass('hvr');

  },function(){

  // On MouseLeave
    $(this).attr('id') = setTimeout(function(){doSomethingHere},66);

  }

);
```

Thanks in advance, Best Regards.

Comment: Whatever you will use as a solution: Please never ever use a string as the first parameter to setTimeout. Use a function reference instead `setTimeout(doSomething, 66)`

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I use a function in the original code, but wanted to shorten it for a better overview. maybe wasn't clear enough though, therefor i edited the code above to avoid future misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you need to keep a reference to the timeout event based on the hovered element, you can use .data() to do that

I think what you are looking for is

```
$("nav a").hover(function () {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('mltimer'));
    $(this).addClass('hvr');
}, function () {
    var timer = setTimeout('doSoemthing()', 66);
    $(this).data('mltimer', timer)
});
```

Comment: that does the trick, perfect. didn't know about data() at all, but seems quite usefull. thank you very much!